# Adding values into war file to yml file from values stored in a .properties file that are stored locally in gradle

Tags: gradle, gradlew, gradle-plugin

I am trying to initialize my dataSource with the help of gradle however gradle is not putting the values into my `yml` that is stored in a .properties on my machine i.e `~/.gradle` and I made a .properties file at that location.

In Gradle I made a method to get the values from the .properties file like so:

```
task copyDBConfig(type: Copy) {

    from 'src/main/resources'
    include 'app.yml'
    into 'build/resources/main'
    expand([
            DB_URI: project.findProperty("dbURI") ?: "",
            DB_USERNAME: project.findProperty("dbUsername") ?: "",
            DB_PASSWORD: project.findProperty("dbPassword") ?: "",
    ])
}

war.finalizedBy(copyDBConfig)
```

Then in my `yml` file I have:

```
spring:
  datasource:
      url: ${DB_URI}
      username: ${DB_USERNAME}
      password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

However when I build the war file and look in the `app.yml` file the correct values are not there, just `${DB_URI}` etc and NOT the strings it should be getting from my .properties file and inputting from into my `app.yml` file.

When I run the app I get the follow error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Driver:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@af2025f returned null for URL:${DB_URI}
```

**Note:** Under `build/resources/main/app.yml` the values from my `app.properties` file are there, just not in the war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup you instruct Gradle that **after** your `war` task is run it should always run the `copyDBConfig` task, which is too late, as the war is already built. Anyway making an own task for this is not the way to go. instead configure the `processResources` task like this:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('app.yml') {
        expand DB_URI: project.findProperty("dbURI") ?: "",
               DB_USERNAME: project.findProperty("dbUsername") ?: "",
               DB_PASSWORD: project.findProperty("dbPassword") ?: ""
    }
}
```